# pandoc.convert pdf formatting in R

Tags: r, pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I am new to R and am trying to convert a markdown document to PDF using the `Pandoc.convert` function.  `Pandoc.convert` creates the PDF just fine, although the border on the document is ridiculously large.  Is there a way to set the border in `Pandoc.convert` to a smaller border?

Example used:

```
Pandoc.convert(f="myfile.md", format="pdf", options="-s")
```

I have tried looking in the Pander package help, and on the Pander site and found no result for [Pandoc.convert](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/faqs.html).

There are three option in pandoc, including: `-V geometry:margin=1in`

Although, I have found none for `Pandoc.convert` specifically.  Is this even possible with just the `Pandoc.convert` command, without getting into LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Pass any number of further options to Pandoc simply by extending your `options` argument, e.g.:

```
Pandoc.convert(f="myfile.md", format="pdf", options="-s -V geometry:margin=1in")
```